# Does not append elements to the first tag

Tags: javascript, html, append, domparser

```js
function $(selector) {

    var resultObject = {
        append: function (element) {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var dos = parser.parseFromString(element, "text/html");

            var all = dos.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
       
            var elemWhichAppend = document.getElementsByTagName(selector);

            var children = all.childNodes;
   
            for (var i = elemWhichAppend.length-1; i >=0; i--) {

                var msgContainer = document.createDocumentFragment();
                var children = all.childNodes;

                for (var child = 0; child < children.length; child++) {
                    var al = children[child];
                    msgContainer.appendChild(al);
                }
                insertAfter(msgContainer, elemWhichAppend[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return resultObject;
}

function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="jqueryjs.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="testing">APPEND</h1>
    <p>Hallo, ich bin ein P TAG </p>
    <h1 class="testing">APPEND2</h1>
    <p>BADGL</p>
    <input type="button" value="append tag/text " onclick="$('p').append('<ul><li>RIBA RIBI<ul><li>FRANK RIBERY</li></ul></li></ul> <h1>NIGOGOG</h1> messi ist scheiße');" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Run code snipped. As you can see the function adds only to the last p element the tags. And forgets the 'messi ist scheiße'. I tried a lot of thinks but I am not able to find my bug. Is it because the 'messi ist scheiße' a text is?

Comment: Maybe your code likes Messi, and refuses to show the abusive text.

Comment: @Teemu Not a bad joke.....

Comment: Like Andi said, the code is a bit too complex, you could get familiar with `insertAdjacentHTML`, it might be a solution to your problem. Create a temporary `div`, use `iAHTML()` to create elements from a string into div, add the content of the div to a document fragment, and append that to elements.

Answer (score 0):

You made this way more complicated than it needs to be.  Just make the append function append your string onto the element's innerHTML.

```js
function $(selector) {
    var resultObject = {
        append: function (element) {
            var elemWhichAppend = document.getElementsByTagName(selector);
            for (var i = elemWhichAppend.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
                elemWhichAppend[i].innerHTML += element;
            }
        }
    }
    return resultObject;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="testing">APPEND</h1>
<p>Hallo, ich bin ein P TAG </p>
<h1 class="testing">APPEND2</h1>
<p>BADGL</p>
<input type="button" value="append tag/text " onclick="$('p').append('<ul><li>RIBA RIBI<ul><li>FRANK RIBERY</li></ul></li></ul> <h1>NIGOGOG</h1> messi ist scheiße');" />
```

Comment: I did this before but my teacher said NO innerHTML. We have to use insertAfter

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping (messi ist scheiße) in a div, p or h1 tag will do the trick.

```
<input type="button" value="append tag/text " onclick="$('p').append('<ul><li>RIBA RIBI<ul><li>FRANK RIBERY</li></ul></li></ul> <h1>NIGOGOG</h1> <p>messi ist scheiße</p>');" />
```

Comment: but what if the user wants only to add a text to the HTML Document? Not a tag?

Comment: Do you have a place for the user to input text?

Comment: No I am just saying because you mentioned that I have to tag my test as a tag. But I just thought what If you want to add a textnode. But I think regular expression would solve it if the user has to put text

Answer (score 0):

On testing this a little in JS fiddle, i found that as you loop through the child elements, for some reason the variable you declared as 'all' seems to be dissappearing, or at least deteriorating in nature to the extent that it doesn't contain any child elements on the second loop, and so does not go through the Child-elements loop the second time around.

One thing that seemed to improve performance was redefining all and dos at the top of the loop:

```
for (var i = elemWhichAppend.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
     var dos = parser.parseFromString(element, "text/html");
     var all = dos.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
     var msgContainer = document.createDocumentFragment();
     ...
```

This should help, as it certainly solved the JSFiddle I was on. I'm not certain why the 'all' variable is changing in nature exactly, but it changes - as i saw from the log - as soon as you perform this line:

```
msgContainer.appendChild(al);
```

I imagine it happens after you perform that line because that line actually accesses the 'document' object and causes it to change (since msgContainer is derived from document object).

Also, you would probably have to include the 'messi ist Shiese' into a html tag, as the line

```
var dos = parser.parseFromString(element, "text/html");
```

This line seems to only find the HTML elements in the element you've provided. You can check this by trying to console.log the 'child' element itself, and you will see that when you include the 'messi ist sheise' part into a tag, it will appear, but it won't appear when it's not in a tag.

```
for (var child = 0; child < children.length; child++) {
     var al = children[child];
     console.log(children[child]);
     msgContainer.appendChild(al);
}
```

Comment: but what if the user wants only to add a text to the HTML Document? Not a tag?

Comment: If the user wants that you have to think of an alternative to this line `var dos = parser.parseFromString(element, "text/html");` -- you need to look for and use a parser method that doesn't require html tags. Also, I would strongly say that in terms of HTML validity, if the user is adding anything to a HTML document, it needs to be inside a HTML tag otherwise it's not valid HTML. So either the user enter's something into a HTML tag, or you yourself manually place it into a HTML tag via your coding. I don't even think the parser will have a method to parse non html and convert it to html

Comment: You should probably create a separate inbetween function that takes all user input that isn't inside a HTML tag, and places it into a P Tag, and then add that to the 'element' variable.

Comment: Also - the last question you just asked me is entirely different from your original question and your original post.

Comment: But does using this technique solve the initial problem? Does it allow you to put the HTML into every p tag instead of just the last?

Comment: Not to every P Tag.... it only does the last. But I think the text is the reason why it only adds to the last p tag...

Comment: Can you put your code into a JSFiddle I can edit at all?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3njwez0j/ But it turns out, at the JSFiddle it does not print anything

Comment: The reason the JSFiddle does not print anything is because you are loading the Javascript in a way that is different to how you are loading it in your initial problem. If you change the 'Load Type' to 'No Wrap <in body>' or 'No Wrap <in head>' (if you click on the 'Javascript' label in the top right of the Javascript window you will see options) and this will accurately emulate the way you are actually loading the Javascript. After doing this, you will notice you are back to your original problem. https://jsfiddle.net/3njwez0j/1/

Comment: In the JSFiddle I have provided above, I have changed the load type of the Javascript. However, you will notice your problem is still there, and the Javascript only updates the last P Tag. This is happening because i don't believe you have fully implemented the solution I had suggested, you didn't add the lines of code into the loop to redefine the 'dos' and the 'all' variable. And so ...

Comment: ... Here is a further updated JSFiddle I did, and you will find that here I have redefined the 'all' and 'dos' variables and it now appends to all the p tags.https://jsfiddle.net/3njwez0j/3/   . I have even added a few extra P Tags just to illustrate it.

Comment: Yeah Thanks. The only problem is the text 'messi... '. But this is also helpful!

Comment: So .. should this not be the accepted answer? Since it answers your original query and main problem, and also gives a pretty detailed explanation, a jFiddle ... etc etc... ;) .

Answer (score -1):

You've missed a "" near getElementsByTagName

Comment: I can't find it? Where do you mean?  I only need "" for the body?

Comment: var elemWhichAppend = document.getElementsByTagName("selector");

Comment: var elemWhichAppend = document.getElementsByTagName("selector"); in this way It should works